# SQL Server trigger : Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used trigger trying to update records from another table using the following statement but I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Here is the code I used

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WO-A] 
ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
AFTER  UPDATE, INSERT, 
AS 
    IF ((SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'Assy' 
            or (SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'L&P' 
            or (SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'ASSY FD'
            or (SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'ASSY BD'

            or (SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'RGA'
            )
        BEGIN
          set nocount on
         IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
         RETURN
    UPDATE T1
    SET 
    [Assembly Notes]=T2.[Assembly Notes],
    [Assy SO Confirm]=T2.[ASSEMBLY LOOKUP C],
    [CALC COLOR]=T2.[COLOR],
    [PILOT SIZE]=T2.[PILOT SIZE2],
    [NO OF HOLES]=T2.[BOLT HOLES2],
    [C/S OD]=T2.[C/S OD2],
    [DISC OD]=T2.[DISC OD],
    [C/S ANGLE2]=T2.[C/S ANGLE2],
    [BH SIZE2]=T2.[BH SIZE2],
    [SHORT WO PN]=t2.[CALC STOCK NO],
    [CALC OFF-SET]=T2.[CALC OFF-SET],
    [RUN OUT LAT]=T2.[RUN OUT LAT],
    [RUN OUT RAD]=T2.[RUN OUT RAD],
    [BOM SECONDRY DISC]=T2.[BOM - SECONDARY DISC],
    [BH SPEC]=T2.[BH SPEC],
    [BH CIRCLE2]=T2.[BH CIRCLE2],
    [DISC THICKNESS2]=T2.[DISC THICKNESS],
    [MRP BOM PARTS 1]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 1 PN],
    [MRP BOM PARTS 2]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 2 PN],
    [MRP BOM PARTS 3]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 3 PN],
    [MRP BOM PARTS 4]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 4 PN],
    --[ASSY PN-S]=T2.[CALC STOCK NO],
    [SHORT WO PN2]=T2.[CALC STOCK NO],
    [WO SALES DESCRIPTION] = T2.[Description for Sales],
    --[Assy SO Confirm]=T2.[Assembly Lookup C],
    [CUSTOMER PN]=T2.[CUSTOMER PN],
    [MRP Wheel]=T2.[BOM WHEEL PN],
    [TIRE PN]=T2.[BOM tire],
    [TIRE SIZE]=T2.[TIRE SIZE],
    [TIRE SUPPLIER]=T22.[Manufacturer],
    [TIRE QUANTITY]=CASE WHEN T1.[TIRE PN]!='' THEN T1.[QUANTITY]
    WHEN T1.[TIRE PN] IS NOT NULL THEN T1.[QUANTITY]
    ELSE ''
    END,
    [RIM PN (MRP)]=t2.[BOM - RIM PN],
    [WO Popularity]=t2.[POPULARITY],
    --[RIM QUANTITY]=t2.[q
    [WEIGHT]=T2.[unitWeight],--?? CHECK WETHER RIGHT COLUMN
    --[ASSY DESC FOR LABEL]
    SIZE=T21.[SIZE],
    [MRP BLK DISC]=T21.[BLK DISC PN],
    [WHEEL PN 1]=NULL,

    [WHEEL PN 1-S]=NULL,
    [ASSY PN-S]=NULL,
    [MO ASSY PN]=null 

 FROM WORKORDERS T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                 FROM [ASSEMBLIES] T2
                 WHERE t1.[ASSY PN] = T2.[ASSEMBLY LOOKUP V 1]) T2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                 FROM [TIRES] T22
                 WHERE T22.[Tire Lookup H] = T2.[BOM Tire] ) T22

    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                 FROM [WHEELS] T21
                 WHERE T2.[BOM WHEEL] = T21.[WHEEL LOOKUP V] ) T21
        END
```

Comment: If you update/insert more than 1 row at a time, you'll get that error from the first IF check ((SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'Assy' .. etc). Always write triggers in a way that will work for multiple rows.

Comment: If two or more rows were inserted, your If clases will get you more than one row and will fail (I believe)

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thank you all!, @marc_s how can i update that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way which should work for multiple row inserts/updates whilst being limited to those ROUTING values.

Note your cross applies really need a order by clause in them, otherwise you're grabbing a random row and may get unexpected results (also probably worth changing the * in each to just a list of the columns you need so the right indexes can used).

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WO-A] 
    ON [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
    AFTER  UPDATE, INSERT, 
    AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
             IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
             RETURN
    ELSE
        UPDATE T1
        SET 
        [Assembly Notes]=T2.[Assembly Notes],
        [Assy SO Confirm]=T2.[ASSEMBLY LOOKUP C],
        [CALC COLOR]=T2.[COLOR],
        [PILOT SIZE]=T2.[PILOT SIZE2],
        [NO OF HOLES]=T2.[BOLT HOLES2],
        [C/S OD]=T2.[C/S OD2],
        [DISC OD]=T2.[DISC OD],
        [C/S ANGLE2]=T2.[C/S ANGLE2],
        [BH SIZE2]=T2.[BH SIZE2],
        [SHORT WO PN]=t2.[CALC STOCK NO],
        [CALC OFF-SET]=T2.[CALC OFF-SET],
        [RUN OUT LAT]=T2.[RUN OUT LAT],
        [RUN OUT RAD]=T2.[RUN OUT RAD],
        [BOM SECONDRY DISC]=T2.[BOM - SECONDARY DISC],
        [BH SPEC]=T2.[BH SPEC],
        [BH CIRCLE2]=T2.[BH CIRCLE2],
        [DISC THICKNESS2]=T2.[DISC THICKNESS],
        [MRP BOM PARTS 1]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 1 PN],
        [MRP BOM PARTS 2]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 2 PN],
        [MRP BOM PARTS 3]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 3 PN],
        [MRP BOM PARTS 4]=T2.[WHL BOM PART 4 PN],
        --[ASSY PN-S]=T2.[CALC STOCK NO],
        [SHORT WO PN2]=T2.[CALC STOCK NO],
        [WO SALES DESCRIPTION] = T2.[Description for Sales],
        --[Assy SO Confirm]=T2.[Assembly Lookup C],
        [CUSTOMER PN]=T2.[CUSTOMER PN],
        [MRP Wheel]=T2.[BOM WHEEL PN],
        [TIRE PN]=T2.[BOM tire],
        [TIRE SIZE]=T2.[TIRE SIZE],
        [TIRE SUPPLIER]=T22.[Manufacturer],
        [TIRE QUANTITY]=CASE WHEN T1.[TIRE PN]!='' THEN T1.[QUANTITY]
        WHEN T1.[TIRE PN] IS NOT NULL THEN T1.[QUANTITY]
        ELSE ''
        END,
        [RIM PN (MRP)]=t2.[BOM - RIM PN],
        [WO Popularity]=t2.[POPULARITY],
        --[RIM QUANTITY]=t2.[q
        [WEIGHT]=T2.[unitWeight],--?? CHECK WETHER RIGHT COLUMN
        --[ASSY DESC FOR LABEL]
        SIZE=T21.[SIZE],
        [MRP BLK DISC]=T21.[BLK DISC PN],
        [WHEEL PN 1]=NULL,

        [WHEEL PN 1-S]=NULL,
        [ASSY PN-S]=NULL,
        [MO ASSY PN]=null 

     FROM WORKORDERS T1
         INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[WORK ORDER #] = i.[WORK ORDER #]
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM [ASSEMBLIES] T2
                     WHERE t1.[ASSY PN] = T2.[ASSEMBLY LOOKUP V 1]) T2
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM [TIRES] T22
                     WHERE T22.[Tire Lookup H] = T2.[BOM Tire] ) T22

        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                     FROM [WHEELS] T21
                     WHERE T2.[BOM WHEEL] = T21.[WHEEL LOOKUP V] ) T21
    WHERE i.ROUTING IN ('Assy', 'L&P', 'ASSY FD', 'ASSY BD', 'RGA')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a subquery from`INSERTED` or `DELETED` tables in a trigger, you should better use a syntax that support multi-row operations.

For example here you used `IF ((SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED) LIKE 'Assy'...`

if this subquery (`SELECT ROUTING FROM INSERTED LIKE 'Assy'`) returns more than one row, then the `if` operation will fail. In this case you can only insert or update one row at a time. so you can't use this query for example:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[WORKORDERS]
SET ROUTING='L'
WHERE ... --Queries that return more than one row
```